# How to update a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the proper way to update a record in Ruby on Rails? Just a single record. For example, I want to modify the name of the title somehow. A code snippet would be awesome!

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: The Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl is a great place to start looking and includes how to use Active Record properly, as well as a lot of other basic Rails information - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Any Rails tutorial or Guide will cover how to do this.

Comment: This has to be one of the laziest questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic way to update a record is like that :

```
@user.name = "new name"
@user.save
```

this assumes that `@user` in an instance of a `User` class having a `name` field.

you can also do mass_assignment with the `update_attributes` method

```
@user.update_attributes name: "new name", email: "new_email@foo.com"
```

If you want an exception to be raised if the record is invalid you can use the bang method instead, so here it would be `save!` & `update_attributes!`

You can also use the `update_attribute` which has been (or will be soon) renamed to `update_column` to update a single column while skipping the validation, but you should generally avoid using this method

more doc [there](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html)

Finally you can use the [write_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) method

Comment: thanks for the direction. i am more of an ios person so this may seem basic. i appreciate the straight forward info.

Answer (score 0):

```
entity = Entity.find_by_name("some_name")
entity.title="new title"
entity.save!
```

or

```
Entity.find_by_name("some_name").update_attributes(:title => "new title")
```

for more details, refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org